# Error with Checking availability of Getters and Setters in Java

Tags: java

this is my first time posting on StackOverflow so I am still getting used to the format. I apologize in advance. Over here, I have 2 classes  FruitBasket and FruitBasketUtility. I've included the getters and setters method in the Fruitbasket.Java. Everything compiled fine but I got an error:

*Fail 1 -- test11addToBasketMethodToAddOneFruitBasketObject::
Check the availability (or) the signature of addToBasket/getFruitBasketList in the FruitBasketUtility class or Setters and Getters in FruitBasket class*

**Main.Java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){


        //For reading input from user
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Creating object of FruitBasketUtility
        FruitBasketUtility fruitBasketUtility = new FruitBasketUtility();


        int choice;
        do{
            //Displaying the menu
            System.out.println("Select an option:");
            System.out.println("1. Add Fruit to Basket");
            System.out.println("2. Calculate Bill");
            System.out.println("3.Exit");


            //Reading the choice
            choice = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();


            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    //Reading fruit details from user
                    System.out.println("Enter the fruit name");
                    String fruitName = in.next();
                    in.nextLine();
                    
                    
                    System.out.println("Enter weight in Kgs");
                    int weightInKgs = in.nextInt();
                    in.nextLine();


                    System.out.println("Enter price per Kg");
                    int pricePerKg = in.nextInt();
                    in.nextLine();


                    FruitBasket fruit = new FruitBasket(fruitName, weightInKgs, pricePerKg);


                    //Adding fruit to basket
                    fruitBasketUtility.addToBasket(fruit);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Calculating and showing the bill
                    ArrayList<FruitBasket> basket = fruitBasketUtility.getFruitBasketList();
                    if(basket.size() > 0){
                        System.out.println("The estimated bill amount is Rs " + fruitBasketUtility.calculateBill((basket.stream())));
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Your basket is empty. Please add fruits.");
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using the application.");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid option. Please try again.");
                    break;
            }

        }while(choice != 3);
    }
}
```

**FruitBasket.Java**

```
    public class FruitBasket {
    //Member variables
    String fruitName;
    int weightInKgs;
    int pricePerKg;


    //Getters and setters
    public void setFruitName(String fruitName){
        this.fruitName =fruitName;
    }


    public void setWeightInKgs(int weightInKgs){
        this.weightInKgs =weightInKgs;
    }


    public void setPricePerKg(int pricePerKg){
        this.pricePerKg =pricePerKg;
    }


    public String getFruitName(){
        return fruitName;
    }


    public int getWeightInKgs(){
        return weightInKgs;
    }


    public int getPricePerKg(){
        return pricePerKg;
    }


    //An empty constructor
    public FruitBasket(){
        fruitName = "";
        weightInKgs = 0;
        pricePerKg = 0;
    }


    //Three argument constructor
    public FruitBasket(String fruitName, int weightInKgs, int pricePerKg){
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
        this.weightInKgs = weightInKgs;
        this.pricePerKg = pricePerKg;
    }
}
```

**FruitBasketUtility.Java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class FruitBasketUtility {
    //Member variables
    ArrayList<FruitBasket> fruitBasketList;


    //Getters and setters
    public void setFruitBasketList(ArrayList<FruitBasket> fruitBasketList){
        this.fruitBasketList = fruitBasketList;
    }


    public ArrayList<FruitBasket> getFruitBasketList(){
        return fruitBasketList;
    }


    //Constructor
    public FruitBasketUtility(){
        fruitBasketList = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    //Add to basket
    public void addToBasket(FruitBasket fObj){
        fruitBasketList.add(fObj);
    }


    //Calculte the bill using stream of FruitBasket
    public int calculateBill(Stream<FruitBasket> fruitBasketStream){
        return fruitBasketStream.mapToInt(x -> x.getPricePerKg() * x.getWeightInKgs()).sum();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the test so that we can see what it is checking for, or is it done via an online portal from your course? You might need to initialize the `ArrayList<FruitBasket> fruitBasketList;` otherwise your `addToBasket` method will fail, for example `ArrayList<FruitBasket> fruitBasketList = new ArrayList<FruitBasket>();` or add a constructor method to the FruitBasketUtility class that initializes the fruitBasketList

Comment: Yes, we do this via Code Editor from my course!

Comment: I copied and ran the code in your question and did not get any errors. Of-course I could not run the test that you claim is failing since I could not find it in your question. Since I can't reproduce your problem, I don't think I can help you resolve it. Consider posting a [mcve].